# Amazon RDS - How to dump contents of an automated snapshot?

Tags: amazon-rds

I searched very long for this problem but I cannot find a solution.

Basically I have a DB Instance running ok, and every day a snapshot is created automatically.

The problem is simply: How to get the contents of the snapshot? I need the contents, but i DO NOT want to overwrite the currently running instance where the snapshot was taken from.

The simplest way would be to use the snapshot and create a new instance from it, dump the contents and remove the instance after this.

I cannot believe that such an easy task is so complicated on amazon RDS (you cannot "dump" the snapshots as they don't seem to be "real" databases).

Is anybody able to describe how this works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you restore the snapshot, you can specify a different "DB Instance Identifier" so you don't overwrite the current instance. Then you can dump the content from this restored instance.